# How to install Filemaker Server 16 on macOS Catalina

Tags: macos-catalina, filemaker

I can't install Filemaker Server 16.0.4.406 on macOS Catalina 10.15.2, every time I get an error.

[image: Screenshot of Filemaker Server 16 installer]

Comment: Your installer says FMS 16 but your comment says FMS 15, what one are you trying to install?

Comment: @SQLTemp - it actually doesn't matter. neither will run on Catalina at all.

Comment: @sqltemp - Filemaker Server 16, I have made mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Only FileMaker 18 & up is capable of running on Catalina - & even that has some issues.

From FileMaker.com - [FileMaker and macOS Catalina Compatibility](https://support.filemaker.com/s/article/FileMaker-and-macOS-Catalina-Compatibility?language=en_US)